# How to convert integer into a string literal?

Tags: r

Is there a function to transform integers into their English equivalents? I.e. to achieve the transformation:

```
some_function(1) = 'one'
```

Comment: Suggest you try googling before posting.  In this case see `replace_number` in qdap.

Comment: or follow this thread: http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/help/05/04/2635.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `english` package

```
library(english)
english(1:10)
# [1] one   two   three four  five  six   seven eight nine  ten
```

Answer (score 3):

```
some_function <- function(i) {
     stopifnot(i %in% 1:9)
     lookup <- c("one", "two", "three",
                 "four", "five", "six",
                 "seven", "eight", "nine")
     lookup[i]
}
```

Modify as needed.